# Implementing ClearTrust Security Valve on Tomcat 7.x with KIE Workbench 6.1.0-Final

Tags: security, tomcat, web-applications, drools, kie

I have created a custom valve implementation for Tomcat 7.x that retrieves the authentication headers passed in by RSA ClearTrust Access Manager.  I have a valve entry in my server.xml and the attendant class in my Tomcat Lib directory.

The problem is that I'm not sure how to configure KIE-Workbench 6.1.0-FINAL to use it.  Do I need to update the KIE web.xml or is there another mechanism?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out.  The code I wrote to solve is on my GitHub (https://github.com/richardmarkle/ctvalve.git).  And the upshot that I learned is that Valves are chained together in the order you define them in the server.xml, where you can restrict it to a context by altering the entry if you so desire.  They are chained together by the ***invoke(request,response)*** method, so at the end of your invoke() implementation, you end with a call to invoke() to call the next Valve.  Took some work to figure this out, I hope this is helpful to someone.